# Do you have to use Github desktop to push files to Github.com?

Tags: github

I am new to web development and it seems like an extra step to have to use a text editor, then transfer files to Github desktop, then to GitHub. Is there a more efficient way to push your content to Github. Also, I am new to stack overflow and I'm excited to be here.

Thank you.

Comment: [Many editors](https://atom.io/) have Git built in, and you can always use [Git itself](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/).

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to use Github Desktop.  Github is just a service that hosts Git repositories.  Git is a version control system and there are zillions of tutorials out on the web that can help get you going learning how to use it.